Кавычки в названиях замков, дворцов, парков
Нужны ли кавычки в названиях: замок Ласточкино гнездо, Воронцовский дворец, Никитский Ботанический сад, парк Айвазовского, Карадагский заповедник?
Склоняюсь к мнению, что не нужны. Насчёт заповедника не знаю. Но не могу найти вменяемый источник по этому вопросу.
Спасибо!


Меньше всего проблем с тремя названиями: Воронцовский дворец, Никитский Ботанический сад,  Карадагский заповедник.

Это имена собственные, пишутся с прописной буквы и без кавычек.

Ласточкино гнездо

«Ласточкино гнездо» — самый красивый замок Крыма и его тайны
В большинстве источников — прописная буква и кавычки.

Парк Айвазовского

Парк Айвазовского — самый сложный вариант, там несколько названий. Кавычки пишутся в официальном названии парка, а в описаниях парк называют по-разному: парк Айвазовское, парк Айвазовского, Парадиз, Партенит. Сам художник Айвазовский к названию отношения не имеет, а его именем был назван поселок Айвазовское.
Название свое Дом отдыха «Айвазовское» получил от поселка, 
некогда бывшего имением Чукурлар княгини Гагариной, а с 1948 
г. носящего имя художника И. К. Айвазовского. Ранее на этих 
землях располагалось имение Кучук-Ламбат, принадлежавшее 
Гагариным и Раевским. На террасах рос виноград, а в гости 
съезжались сплошь именитые посетители Крыма.

Примеры названий в текстах
Но предметом нашей экскурсии был памятник садово-паркового искусства местного значения — Парк на территории Лечебно-оздоровительного комплекса "Айвазовское". Посетители парка дали ему название Парадиз (в переводе с греческого — библейский рай). Парк был заложен в середине 60-х годов XX века, а его основой послужило образцовое садовое помещичье хозяйство графа Раевского.
Парк «Айвазовское» в Партените («Парадиз») работает с 9:00 до 18:30 ежедневно. Парк находится в поселке Партенит — это посередине между Ялтой и Алуштой.
Парк Айвазовского. История создания парка Айвазовское.
Вывод: парк со строчной буквы, кавычек нет, но есть два варианта названий. Более правильно — парк Айвазовское, но не исключено, что чаще его называют парк Айвазовского.

ФГБУ САНАТОРИЙ "АЙВАЗОВСКОЕ" УПРАВЛЕНИЯ ДЕЛАМИ ПРЕЗИДЕНТА РФ - название организации, ещё с регистром можно не заморачиваться)

Имейте в виду: После оплаты вешают на руку бумажный оранжевый браслет.

@Sharon, спасибо за ваш труд! Тоже смотрю официальные названия и примеры употребления. Думала, может, ещё какие-то источники есть. Вы развеяли мои сомнения.

Спасибо вам за вопрос.  Тема была познавательная во всех отношениях)
